# How can I write an mdx query that slices by both a date range and dimension member value

Tags: mdx, mondrian

I need to write an mdx query that limits its results by the value of a dimension but also by a date range. I know how to do one or the other but I can't figure out how to do both at once.

This works for the date range:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Hours]} ON COLUMNS, [Time Type].[Type].Members ON ROWS 
FROM [cube]
WHERE {[Date].[Date ISO].[2013-01-26]:[Date].[Date ISO].[2013-06-25]}
```

And this works for the member slicer:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Hours]} ON COLUMNS, [Time Type].[Type].Members ON ROWS 
FROM [cube]
WHERE [Time Type].[Allocation Type].[Direct]
```

How do I constrain the results by both of these WHERE clause values at the same time? I've tried putting them both in the same WHERE like so:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Hours]} ON COLUMNS, [Time Type].[Type].Members ON ROWS 
FROM [cube]
WHERE ([Time Type].[Allocation Type].[Direct],
    {[Date].[Date ISO].[2013-01-26]:[Date].[Date ISO].[2013-06-25]})
```

but Mondrian replies with: No function matches signature (, ).

Note that Mondrian does not support subqueries or I would do it that way.

I think I might need to use a filter function on my rows for my member constraint but I need to filter on something that I don't want to display, which I am not sure how to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think crossjoin is the answer like so:

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Hours]} ON COLUMNS, [Time Type].[Type].Members ON ROWS 
FROM [cube]
WHERE CROSSJOIN([Time Type].[Allocation Type].[Direct],
    {[Date].[Date ISO].[2013-01-26]:[Date].[Date ISO].[2013-06-25]})
```

CROSSJOIN creates all the combinations of the 'Direct" member and the dates in my range as tuples for my WHERE slicer. I think this is the right answer.