# Two Conditions Where MDX Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, mdx, pentaho, mondrian

i'm new in MDX world and i'm having some doubt in where clausule.

I have this query

```
WITH
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[Product].[All Products]}
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Quantity]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [SteelWheelsSales]
WHERE ([Time].[2003] : [Time].[2004])
```

And i want to add this clausule to where.

```
[Markets].[EMEA].[Ireland]
```

What i have to do? I already try this: `WHERE ([Time].[2003] : [Time].[2004], [Markets].[EMEA].[Ireland])`

Please, help me guys?

Comment: When you say it isn't working, can you elaborate a bit? MDX WHERE clauses aren't like SQL WHERE clauses, but all of your hierarchies are independent, so there's no reason you can't build a set expression for your slicer axis.

Comment: @Caio: You could try `WHERE CrossJoin([Time].[2003] : [Time].[2004], [Markets].[EMEA].[Ireland])` as it is done here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17310762/how-can-i-write-an-mdx-query-that-slices-by-both-a-date-range-and-dimension-memb

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why @whytheq's solution didn't work for you. This is similar and should work:

```
WITH
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[Product].[All Products]}
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Quantity]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [SteelWheelsSales]
WHERE ({[Time].[2003] : [Time].[2004]} * {[Markets].[EMEA].[Ireland]})
```

Or you could go for nested sub selects:

```
WITH
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[Product].[All Products]}
SELECT
NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Quantity]} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM (
       SELECT [Markets].[EMEA].[Ireland] ON 0 
       FROM (
             SELECT {[Time].[2003] : [Time].[2004]} ON 0 
             FROM [SteelWheelsSales]
            )
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

If you aggregate it in the WITH clause first then use aggregation in WHERE does it still complain?

```
WITH
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[Product].[All Products]}
SET [dts] AS
    {[Time].[2003] : [Time].[2004]}
MEMBER [Time].[All].[dts] AS
    AGGREGATE([dts])
SELECT
  NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Quantity]} ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [SteelWheelsSales]
WHERE ([Time].[All].[dts], [Markets].[EMEA].[Ireland]);
```

But maybe just being explicit in the WHERE clause by using `{..}` helps:

```
WITH
SET [~ROWS] AS
    {[Product].[All Products]}
SELECT
  NON EMPTY {[Measures].[Quantity]} ON COLUMNS,
  NON EMPTY [~ROWS] ON ROWS
FROM [SteelWheelsSales]
WHERE (
     {[Time].[2003] : [Time].[2004]}
    , [Markets].[EMEA].[Ireland]);
```

Comment: Both solutions didn't workout. I have already tried the second one. When I make:       
    WHERE ([Markets].[EMEA].[Ireland]) works fine.

Comment: If you say `WHERE WHERE ([Time].[2003])` what do you get? Also if you say  `WHERE WHERE ([Time].[2004])` what do you get? Please tell me both results.

Comment: If i put two WHERE, don't work. but with only one WHERE works fine

Comment: Sorry the `WHERE WHERE` is a typo. So if you put `WHERE ([Time].[2003])` it works fine? Then if you change to `WHERE ([Time].[2004])` it also works fine?